# Requesting soft input method in fragment works sporadically

Tags: android

I have a fragment that contains an `EditText`. The goal is to show the soft keyboard immediately upon navigating to this fragment.

Requesting the soft input method "on demand", as described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility#ShowOnDemand), produces sporadic results.. with the keyboard sometimes being shown, and other times not.

Possibly of note:

1. I am running on a device, not an emulator.
2. Using `SHOW_FORCED` instead of `SHOW_IMPLICIT` produces the same
   sporadic results.
3. `isFocusable` and `isFocusableInTouchMode` are both enabled
4. `requestFocus()` always returns `true`, even when the keyboard
   is not shown
5. (See edit) Navigating *from* a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    binding.editTextView.apply {
        if (requestFocus()) {
            val imm = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**

The fragment prior to the fragment containing the `EditText` is a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

I changed my navigation flow to bypass the dialog (so now I'm navigating from a regular `Fragment` to the fragment containing the `EditText`) and the the keyboard seems to show every time (tested it about 20 times).

With this discovery, it's possible that the issue is connected to navigating from a dialog. Perhaps when the dialog is dismissed, it sometimes registers another touch event that dismisses the keyboard before it even has time to show.. not sure.

Comment: Have you tried doing it somewhere other than onViewCreated?  That may be too early in the lifecycle of the view to work properly.

Comment: Hmm, I will give that a go. Thanks. I also discovered that the issue might be related with the fact that I'm navigating from a dialog fragment (see edit).

Comment: Set this     android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" in activity. Hence, irrespective of Fragments, it will keep opened soft keyboard.